# exposing functions within functions

Tags: php, function, class

I need some help with this.  I'm developing a larger php app, and a making different kind of functions to be used in this framework.

But I'm at a lost on how the best practice is making a function with different functions within it, but with these functions separate in different files for easy categorization.

Let me show what I want, I'll like to just call a simple function and then have exposed different functions within that. like this

```
$input = app::getInput();
$input->filter('this string');
$input->validate('other string');
```

But with these different function in different files.
Right now I'm doing this like this, but I don't think that's the best practice and I'm at a loss on how to do it better.

```
file: app.php
class app {
    public static function getInput {
        return new Input;
    }
}


file: inputFilter.php
abstract class InputFilter {
    public function filter() {
    }
}

file: inputValidate.php
abstract class InputValidate extends InputFilter {
    public function validate() {
    }
}

file: inputHelper.php
class Input extends InputValidate {
    public function someorhterfunction(){
    }
}
```

This will expose the functions to be used in the example above, but how do I produce the same result but without having to extend the classes every time I want to give input a new function?

hope this makes sense ...

EDIT: Okay one point missing, is of cause that i want to be able to extend `InputValidate`and `InputFilter` with more functonality.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? I can't really see any point. Wouldn't it make more sense to declare all those abstract functions in a base class and extend from that?

Comment: In any case, `Input` is not a `InputValidate`. Extending a class from another one must respect the semantical "is-a" relation between them. You can instead create separate classes, like `InputValidator`, etc, with corresponding methods, which could receive the input (value) as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just make one big class `Input`:

```
class Input {
    public function filter($param) {}
    public function validate($param) {}
    public function someotherfunction() {}
}
```

As long as you don't think, that you will have other class extending `InputValidate` and `InputFilter` there will be no problem.

Comment: yeah but that's is why im asking, because i am planing to extend InputValidate with more functionality, and also having them exposed to use.